# VBA AddDate based on userform entry

Tags: vba

I'm trying to manipulate a date with a userform. The userform has a text box where you enter a date, then I have a dropdown where you select a number.

The number you select determines how many months are added to the date. If you put 1/1/2017 and select 3, then you should get 4/1/2017. The issue is that when I use the AddDate function, it will not let me use this:

```
AddDate("m", Userform1.ComboBox1.Value, Userform1.TextBox1.Value)
```

It will not let me pull values from the userform. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cast the userform value as a date e.g. 'Cdate(userform1.Value')

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean set "Cdate As Date" and "CDate = Userform2.ComboBox1.Value"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With UserForm1
    .TextBox1.Value = DateAdd("m", .ComboBox1.Value, CDate(.TextBox1.Value))
End With
```